# Reading a file from Google Cloud Storage with XLRD (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, xlrd

Im trying to read a file stored in one of my buckets in GAE.

The file is stored in a public bucket

I've tried to:

```
archivo=cloudstorage.open('/bucket/workbook.xlsx')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=archivo)
```

but xlrd expect to open the file by itself, so I get a TypeError

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ReadBuffer found

Is there any way to give xlrd an open file so I can read the file without having to change xlrd.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should read the documentation with more attention before asking stuff...

To provide xlrd with an open file, instead of a filename, I have to give a filecontent.

This is done by:

```
archivo=cloudstorage.open('/bucket/workbook.xlsx')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=archivo.read())
```

Comment: Great, so please accept your own answer to this Q correctly shows as closed!

Comment: it not yet possible. I have to wait 2 days to do so. Or someone has to accept my ansqwer so I can accept it.